# How to use React JS component in Html directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its easy to use a React component in JS/ES6 like:

```
 <Header />
```

I want to be able to use React component in pure html the way we use builtin html tags eg.

```
 <p>para</p>
```

Comment: If you want to use a React component you will need to use ReactDOM.render() function on an element. There is no other way to do so

Comment: I think we should be able to write React component in Html, because the parent is attached to a div any way e.g. render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById('app')); So if the parent Component could be attached to an html div then any component should be done so.

Comment: A component can only be rendered through `render(<Compopnent />, element)` or within another component `render` function. React application are fully build in javascript (that's a facebook design choice). In a react component you're not writing any HTML, only JSX (wich is Javascript underneath) if you want component that could be used on any HTML. I suggest you to give a look at Polymer.